# Confirmation, Developer and Personal Separate FB accounts allowed

Tags: facebook

I need to know if it's possible to use a separate Facebook account to my personal one for building apps (i'd rather not fill my personal account with development spam). Facebook's terms of agreement do state that I'm allowed only one account, but people on various forums are speaking about using two separate accounts without issue.

I'd rather not get red flagged, does anyone know officially if I'm allowed to open a separate account in a professional capacity?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it within FB's TOS is to have a single account.

Comment: Seconded, it's very expressly forbidden - https://www.facebook.com/terms.php section 4